# Oracle 12c - select records within a window

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have the following sample records:

```
log_id employee_id
12345  99999      
12346  99999      
12347  88888      
12357  88888
```

How do I filter records where log_id = 12345, 12346 (log_id only 1 number apart) when there duplicate employee_id's? Output should be:

```
log_id employee_id
12345  99999      
12346  99999
```

Comment: So the `log_id` is the primary key column. Are there gaps in `log_id` values, as in your example (between 12347 and 12357), or is your example a simplification? What's the expected result, if there's an additional row with `log_id` value of 12358 and `employee_id` of 99999 added to your sample data? How about with 12344 and 99999?

Comment: There could be possibilities of having gaps, This is a part of a bigger query i'm working on and I just want to make sure my sub query returns only those records that have this satisfied along with another column not presented here. The first expected result will still show the same result, without 12358. 2nd scenario is not expected.

Answer (score 4):

I would not use window functions.  I would simply use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t tnext
              where tnext.log_id = t.log_id + 1 and tnext.employee_id = t.employee_id) or
      exists (select 1
              from t tprev
              where tprev.log_id = t.log_id - 1 and tprev.employee_id = t.employee_id);
```

This query should be able to take advantage of an index on `(employee_id, log_id)`.

Comment: not sure but may be you can check + 1 and - 1 in a single exists

Comment: The PK is on log_id only.

Comment: The query will still benefit from the PK and it should be an efficient index seek (unless the whole query has more to it, than just that).

Comment: @user3224907 . . . That should be okay with this structure.  There is only one matching record, so having the `employee_id` in the index is just preventing a data page reference.

Comment: @SalmanA . . . You can.  And Oracle probably has a good enough optimizer to do the right thing.  I tend to split this logic out because `OR` (or `IN`) can sometimes kill query performance.

Comment: I don't understand how this works. Isn't this just going to show all records from my table (t)? I want to show only the record set that has log_id and log_id + 1 have the same employee_id.

Comment: @user3224907 . . . That is what the second condition in the correlated subquery does.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
with 
x as (
  select log_id, employee_id, row_number() over(order by log_id) as rn
  from my_table
),
y as (
  select
    log_id, employee_id, rn,
    lag(log_id) over(order by rn) as prev_log_id,
    lead(log_id) over(order by rn) as next_log_id
from x
)
select log_id, employee_id from y
where log_id - 1 = prev_log_id or prev_log_id is null
  and log_id + 1 = next_log_id or next_log_is is null
order by rn
```

Comment: You could simplify it, as @GordonLinoff has stated, that the `log_id` is the primary key (so you do not need the `row_number` first step and can just use `over(order by log_id)`). The issue is, that Gordon only wants the rows which have same `epmployee_id` for subsequent `log_id` values, and you are not testing for `employee_id` in your queries. You should probably have your `lead` and `lag` actually pull the next/previous `log_id` and `epmployee_id` and then filter by checking if current `employee_id` is the same as previous/next, beside checking if previous/next `log_id` is off by 1.

Comment: @Hilarion Yeah, if `log_id` is a PK then my answer is too complex.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:

```
SQL> with test (log_id, employee_id) as
  2    (select 12345, 99999 from dual union all
  3     select 12346, 99999 from dual union all
  4     select 12344, 99999 from dual union all  --> added this one
  5     --
  6     select 12347, 88888 from dual union all
  7     select 12357, 88888 from dual
  8    )
  9  select log_id, employee_id
 10  from test
 11  where employee_id in (select employee_id
 12                        from test
 13                        group by employee_id
 14                        having max(log_id) - min(log_id) = count(*) - 1
 15                       );

    LOG_ID EMPLOYEE_ID
---------- -----------
     12344       99999
     12346       99999
     12345       99999

SQL>
```

Comment: The question is, if we want to get the result only when all `employee_id` values are consecutive, or only those, that are consecutive. Add an entry with `log_id` of 12358 and `employee_id` of 99999 to your sample data. Should we return nothing or the 3 first entries of the sample?

Comment: That's true. :) I just wanted to point that specific trait of your approach, and was not how I initially understood the question. Your take on it made me see, that the question may be interpreted differently.

Comment: Based on the clarification from @user3224907, it would seem, that your approach will not fulfill the expectation. :/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this table structure:

```
create table test (
  log_id number(5) primary key,
  employee_id number(5) not null
)
```

This sample data:

```
insert into test
   (select 12342, 99999 from dual union all
    select 12343, 77777 from dual union all
    select 12344, 99999 from dual union all
    select 12345, 99999 from dual union all
    select 12346, 99999 from dual union all
    select 12347, 88888 from dual union all
    -- gap
    select 12357, 88888 from dual union all
    select 12358, 33333 from dual union all
    select 12359, 33333 from dual
   )
```

You could do it with this query:

```
with x as (
 select log_id,
        employee_id,
        lead(log_id) over (order by log_id) as next_log_id,
        lag(log_id) over (order by log_id) as previous_log_id,
        lead(employee_id) over (order by log_id) as next_employee_id,
        lag(employee_id) over (order by log_id) as previous_employee_id
 from test
)
select log_id, employee_id
  from x
 where (log_id = next_log_id - 1 and employee_id = next_employee_id)
    or (log_id = previous_log_id + 1 and employee_id = previous_employee_id)
 order by 1
```

With this result:

```
LOG_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID
-------+------------
 12344 |       99999
 12345 |       99999
 12346 |       99999
 12358 |       33333
 12359 |       33333
```

If you are guaranteed, to have the `LOG_ID` value sequence without gaps (as the sample has in range from 12342 to 12347), you could use a simpler variant:

```
with x as (
 select log_id,
        employee_id,
        lead(employee_id) over (order by log_id) as next_employee_id,
        lag(employee_id) over (order by log_id) as previous_employee_id
 from test
 where log_id between 12342 and 12347
)
select log_id, employee_id
  from x
 where employee_id in (previous_employee_id, next_employee_id)
 order by 1
```

You can see it in action at [this Oracle LiveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/hndajg1y1fzv5d3jq7wpaiarq) or this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8b56/7).